# Can't install wi fi driver windows 10

Tags: windows, wifi-driver

Everything worked fine on my laptop emachines 725 till I reinstalled windows.

When I try to install driver I get an error:
the devise could not be present or may be unplugged from the system.
Below is the screen of my network adapters:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't see any Wi-Fi adapters on this list, it may be disabled. This laptop seems to have a hardware Wi-Fi switch, have you tried to press it?

Comment: yes, no effects

Comment: Some BIOS allow enabling/disabling of several components. Check that first. If there's no such option, remove and re-seat the WiFi card.

Comment: how do I remove wificard?